# Is aggregated poisson-distributed data still poisson-distributed?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, count-data, poisson-regression

I want to aggregate a dataset which is Poisson-distributed in which each event that occurs is measured at a different time. The data is transformed into transactional data, aggregated on UserID.

So each user has a sum of each event that happened throughout the total measured time period. Next I want to perform a regression. My question is, can I still perform a Poisson regression or should I perform something else? Example of data is the picture below.

[image: Example data]

Comment: The sum of independent Poissons is Poisson, but a sum of dependent Poissons might also be Poisson (with the right forms of dependence). It may be that a Poisson will be a reasonable approximation to the conditional distribution of the counts that you have..

Comment: @Glen_b Can you give an example of dependent Poissons whos sum is Poisson? Their existence seemssomewhat contradiced by jbowman comment here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22179/dependent-thinning-poisson-process

Comment: Sorry to give you the wrong impression. I wasn't claiming to know of the existence of such a result; rather I was trying to point out that in a  statement of the form "if the Poissons are independent, their sum is Poisson" that the "*if*" was not necessarily an "*iff*"; and in any case that makes no direct claim about conditional distributions. My comment in the second sentence about conditional distributions included the phrase "may be [...] a reasonable approximation", so there's no actual claim of any actual Poisson result in that part either.

Comment: jbowman's comment about the restricted form of such dependence at the end is certainly correct (that the correlation must be 0).